# Showing items with php and JSON dropdown

Tags: php, json

I got a sizing chart and I only want to show one result at the time next to the description of what that size means.

Example: I want to output B+C if id is 01, but that's using the CSV, not the JSON file I made!

How to make the php to show only the "ID": "01" items?

Then just show values from "name" and just from "2xs"

And thirdly with a dropdown choice another size and then it will show that.

[image]

So far I made my CSV into a JSON file, but I don't understand how to output the data.

```js
{
  "ID": "01",
  "name": "Height",
  "2XS": 66,
  "XS": 68,
  "S": 70,
  "M": 72,
  "L": 74,
  "XL": 76,
  "2XL": 78,
  "3XL": 80,
  "4XL": 82,
  "5XL": "",
  "6XL": "",
  "7XL": "",
  "8XL": "",
  "9XL": "",
  "10XL": ""
}
```

This is how far I'm at on the php side:

```
<?php
$json=file_get_contents("/sizes.json");
$result = json_decode(true);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Here is an example of how I want it to be shown:
[image]

Comment: Can you add what you expect the output to be? It is hard to tell from your question.

Comment: Please search JSON cascading dropdown PHP AJAX - you can send the JSON to the browser and have it handle the object

Comment: I will look in to this as soon as i got the data i want to be shown!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the PHP if the chart is in the same page as the HTML

I use jQuery here to give an example.

```js
var item = {
"ID": "01",
  "sizes" :  {
"Height":          { "2XS": 66,"XS": 68,"S": 70,"M": 72,"L": 74,"XL": 76,"2XL": 78,"3XL": 80,"4XL": 82,"5XL": ""},
"Width under arm": { "2XS": 46,"XS": 68,"S": 70,"M": 72,"L": 74,"XL": 76,"2XL": 78,"3XL": 80,"4XL": 82,"5XL": ""},
"Bottom width":    { "2XS": 46,"XS": 68,"S": 70,"M": 72,"L": 74,"XL": 76,"2XL": 78,"3XL": 80,"4XL": 82,"5XL": ""},
"Neck openeing":   { "2XS": 46,"XS": 68,"S": 70,"M": 72,"L": 74,"XL": 76,"2XL": 78,"3XL": 80,"4XL": 82,"5XL": ""},
"Arm openeing":    { "2XS": 18,"XS": 68,"S": 70,"M": 72,"L": 74,"XL": 76,"2XL": 78,"3XL": 80,"4XL": 82,"5XL": ""} // no comma
  }
}

  /* the above could be
    $.get("items.php?id=01",function(data) {
      var item = JSON.parse(data); // not necessary to parse if the server returns aplicate/json
    });
  */

var names = {
  "2XS": "XX Small",
  "XS": "X Small",
  "S": "Small",
  "M": "Medium",
  "L": "Large",
  "XL": "X large",
  "2XL": "XX Large",
  "3XL": "XXX Large",
  "4XL": "XXXX Large",
  "5XL": "XXXXX Large"
}
$(function() {
  var $sel = $("#sel1"); // cache the object for reuse
  $.each(item.sizes.Height, function(key, val) { // create the select from the object above - I use the Height list of sizes
    if (val) { // ignore empty sizes
      $sel.append($('<option/>', {
        "value": key,
        "text": names[key]
      }));
    }
  });
  $sel.on("change", function() {
    process(this.value); // pass select value to process
  }).change(); // trigger the current selection 
});

function process(aSize) { // passes XS ... 5XL
  var $table = $("#sizeTable").empty();
  $.each(item.sizes, function(key, val) { // loop over height, width, 
    $table.append('<tr><td class="nameCell">' + key + '</td><td class="sizeCell">' + val[aSize] + ' cm</td></tr>')
  });
}
```

```css
.nameCell {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.sizeCell {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel1"></select>
<table>
  <tbody id="sizeTable"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not exactly like how i wanted it, but for sure with your code and a couple of hours figure out how u did that i can figure out how to do it the way i want it!. Thanks mate!

Comment: Dude your code is to advanced for me.. First i want the functions to run outside the JSON file as this file is automatic generated ones a day. But i dont think this is not possible as i need "var items"? And i have NO idea how to get all the numbers listed next to the names. Im sorry mate!
kind of
echo : name01;
echo : 2XS01:
echo : name02;
echo : 2XS02;

Comment: Have a look at the example #1 I posted now

Comment: It's bedtime here so I'll look tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but to just display the object properties you mentioned you can:

```
<?php
// Get file and decode.
$json=file_get_contents("/sizes.json");
$result = json_decode($string, true);

// Access specific object properties.
$id = $result->ID;
$name = $result->name;
$size = $result->{'2XS'};

// Outputs '01 Height 66'
echo $id . ' ' . $name . ' ' . $size;
?>
```

Comment: The server should send JSON to the browser using AJAX and have the client parse it

Comment: @mplungjan If you want to do something with AJAX then you also need to give us your front end code that will be making the request and parsing the response (or as close to what you think it should be as you can). Your initial question doesn't do a good job of making what you are trying to do clear.

Comment: Thanks, but your code did not output anything. Sorry for my swinglish or maybe because its 03:00 in the morning.. I will mock around until i get it.. I just dont get my head around this..